# Dynamic ID's in jquery selectors not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I tried this, but ajax calling two times to PHP file or Diplaying else part two times. please help me. I called editCat() in button

**EDIT HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="editCat(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
</button>
<div id="edittextdiv_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter categorie name" id="edittextinput_<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function editCat(id) {
    $('#edittextdiv_'+id+'').toggle();
    $('#edittextinput_'+id+'').keyup(function(event){
        var category = $(this).val();
        var firstletter = category.charAt(0);
        var capitalreg = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]*$/);
        if(capitalreg.test(firstletter) && category != ''){
            if(event.keyCode == 13){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"edit_cat.php",
                    type:"post",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{category:category, item_id:id},
                    success:function(response) {
                        if (response.success == true) {

                        }
                    }
                });
            } 
        } else {
            $('#edittextinput_'+id+'').after("<p class='text-danger'>Enter first letter in capital</p>");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Provide the *parsed* HTML, also are the HTML elements dynamically generated? Also your event handlers shouldn't be within a function, that means they may not be set if you never called `editCat`.

Comment: <input name="" placeholder="Enter categorie name" id="edittextinput_1" value="Frocks" type="text">

Comment: but i want to call event to trigger enter key

Comment: please provide the solution sir

Comment: From where your are calling `editCat` function?

Comment: @Mahbubul Islam I updated my html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can avoid using
     `$('#edittextinput_'+id+'').keyup()`
 as it is unnecessary to call keyup function  inside another function

please call `onkeyup` javascript function in input button

```
  <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter categorie name" id="edittextinput_<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" onkeyup="editCat('<?php echo $row['id'];?>',this)" >
```

and please see my snippet to

```js
function check_key(id,cc,event) {

        /*$('#edittextdiv_'+id).toggle(); toggle */
        var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
        var jq = $(cc);
        var category =jq.val();
        var firstletter = category.charAt(0);
        var capitalreg = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]*$/);
        if(capitalreg.test(firstletter) && category != ''){
            
            if(event.keyCode == 13){
            alert('ajax code');
                $.ajax({
                    url:"edit_cat.php",
                    type:"post",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{category:category, item_id:id},
                    success:function(response) {
                          
                        if (response.success == true) {

                        }
                    }
                });
            } 
        }else {
            /*alert('else code')*/
            $('#edittextinput_'+id).after("<p class='text-danger'>Enter first letter in capital</p>");
        }
}
function editCat(id) {

    $('#edittextdiv_'+id+'').toggle();
    
        var category = $('#edittextinput_'+id+'').val();
        var firstletter = category.charAt(0);
        var capitalreg = new RegExp(/^[A-Z]*$/);
        if(capitalreg.test(firstletter) && category != ''){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"edit_cat.php",
                    type:"post",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{category:category, item_id:id},
                    success:function(response) {
                        if (response.success == true) {

                        }
                    }
                });
        } else {
            $('#edittextinput_'+id+'').after("<p class='text-danger'>Enter first letter in capital</p>");
        }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edittextdiv_1">
    <input type="text" name="1" placeholder="Enter categorie name" id="edittextinput_1" onkeyup="check_key('1',this,event)" value="test">
</div><br>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="editCat(1)">
    test
</button>
```

Comment: please try my answer @Bhaskararao Gummidi

Comment: but i want to toggle the input textbox and call to ajax when input box triggered by enter key

Comment: please see my snippet you can also toggle input textbox and after user press enter button you can send ajax code

Comment: Sir your code is working for ajax call but i want to toggle textbox when button is clicked. I updated my HTML code. please see once @Pritamkumar

Comment: please mark answer if my answer solved your problem @BhaskararaoGummidi